# Why is the compiler adding padding to a struct that's already 4-byte aligned?

Tags: c, gcc

This issue has been reproduced using multiple 32-bit architectures

I have the following struct in which the sum of all the data member sizes is 76 bytes:

```
typedef struct
{


    uint32_t unused_32;

    //Unrolled arrays
    uint8_t ar1_1;
    uint8_t ar1_2;

    uint8_t ar2_1;
    uint8_t ar2_2;

    uint8_t ar3_1;
    uint8_t ar3_2;

    uint8_t ar4_1;
    uint8_t ar4_2;
    uint8_t ar4_3;
    uint8_t ar4_4;
    uint8_t ar4_5;
    uint8_t ar4_6;


    uint8_t ex1;
    uint8_t ex2;
    uint8_t ex3;
    uint8_t ex4;
    uint8_t fsi_1;
    uint8_t fsi_2;
    uint8_t fsi_3;
    uint8_t fsi_4;


    uint64_t ex5;
    uint64_t ex6;
    uint64_t Unused_1;
    uint64_t Unused_2;
    uint64_t Unused_3;
    uint64_t Unused_4;

    uint32_t Crc;       

} testStruct;
```

However, when I do a sizeof() on the struct I get 80 bytes and I'm having trouble figuring out why. When I set the preprocessor to use the "#pragma pack(1)" option and do a sizeof(), it returns 76 bytes, indicating that the compiler is adding padding.

I printed out the addresses of every data member of the structure and everything is in sequential order in memory with no 'holes'. I also added an initialization for a 32-bit integer before the struct and printed out its address, and it came right before the first datamember of the struct, indicating that the padding that's being added is at the end.

76 bytes is already 4-byte aligned, why is the compiler adding an additional 4 bytes onto the end of the struct to make it 80 bytes?

Comment: Because it wants it to be 8-byte aligned? `uint64_t` is 8-byte.

Comment: Probably some extra padding between `fsi_4` and `ex5`.

Comment: How it padding **at the end** related to alignment **at the beginning**? And why not? provide a reference to the standard disallowing this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: These are the addresses of those data members: fsi_4 address: 41973f4f, ex5 address: 41973f50. There's only a byte in between them, so the padding doesn't seem to be added there. Like I said, after examining the addresses of each data member, everything seems to come in sequential order so I think the padding must come at the end of the struct.

Comment: Side comment: this question is yet another demonstration of why worrying about struct padding is almost always a waste of time.  You only care about struct padding if, for some reason, you're trying to get your struct to conform to some externally-imposed storage layout.  But there are other, more portable techniques for performing I/O based on externally-imposed storage layouts -- use them!

Comment: Are you compiling **for** 32-bit architecture (rather than **on** a 32-bit machine)?

Comment: Padding is not limited to align the members within a struct. If you create an array with this struct type, each array element must be aligned as well. In this case, 8 byte alignment is required for the uint64 part.

Comment: A detailed information on structure packing and padding can be found at [Art of Structure packing in C](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

Comment: these lines: ` uint64_t ex5;
    uint64_t ex6;
    uint64_t Unused_1;
    uint64_t Unused_2;
    uint64_t Unused_3;
    uint64_t Unused_4;` in the struct are 8 bytes each, so the overall struct must be 8 byte aligned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

> Note that the alignment of any given struct or union type is required by the ISO C standard to be at least a perfect multiple of the lowest common multiple of the alignments of all of the members of the struct or union in question.

In other words, because your struct contains members of type `uint64_t` (aligned to 8 bytes), the struct itself must be aligned to an 8-byte boundary.

Comment: Confirmed that if I replace each uint64 with 2 uint32s the compiler doesn't add padding. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, the only "modern" 32-bit ABI where 64-bit types only need 4-byte alignment that I'm aware of is 32-bit x86. Almost everywhere else (notably ARM) the ABI requires 8-byte alignment.

Comment: @R.. Note: The embedded devices I use oblige a 2 byte alignment for integers16 through 64-bit.  These devices are plentiful in 2017.  Of course that is not gcc as post is tagged.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with the rational: "because your struct contains members of type uint64_t (8 bytes), it must be aligned to an 8-byte boundary."  For a given member, the issues is not _size_, but _alignment_ requirement.  It happens to be the same for OP.  Yet, as the doc says "lowest common multiple of the _alignments_"

Answer (score 2):

As OP was able to use `#pragma pack(1)`, an implementation specific directive,  it implies that the size of the structure *could* be packed to 76 bytes rather than 80 on OP's platform.

With such packing, an array of `testStruct` would certainly cause `uint64_t` members to occur on non-octal addresses.  By padding the structure with 4, an array of `testStruct`, starting on an octal address would have **all `uint64_t` members in each element aligned for potential optimal code/speed.**

This is a common trade off compilers make to optimize, code, speed and memory usage.

---

Most coding tasks should not assume a packed structure.

For code that needs precise layout, either implementation directive like `#pragma pack(1)` are needed or for portability, another non-`struct` approach is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler use 4 bytes boundary till fsi_4, then use 8 bytes boundary once declaration of "uint64_t" started thats why you are getting 80 bytes of total size.